# Removing "&" sign in highlighted text by a context menu item

Tags: c, windows, contextmenu

I need to remove `&` sign in highlighted text. I want to add a context menu item on highlighted text to run the program and  removing `&` sign from the text. My text can be in telegram software [desktop](https://desktop.telegram.org/) or [web](https://web.telegram.org/#/im) edition and I want to use C language on windows.

how to add the program in the context menu for the highlighted text?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Add some tags. What platform/OS ? Which kind of browser / file editor / software ? Unfortunately, software engineering isn't magic, you may not achieve a one-language-for-one-use thing in your case. Start where you need it the most : a browser plugin for example.

Comment: Thanks JoeBilly for your suggestion.